# How to use a computed property and Vuex, without getting reactivity errors

Tags: vue.js

I would like to understand when you can use a computed property like this:

```
computed: {
 selectedDate () {
  return this.$store.getters['stockProposal/getDateEndArticle']
 }
}
```

Where the getter is defined as follows:

```
getDateEndArticle: state => {
  return state.articleSettings['date_end']
}
```

Where in the template I then use:

```
v-model="selectedDate"
```

Sometimes this works for me, but often I get the following error 'Property or method "selectedDate" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.'

Can someone explain to me why this is not always working?

I also tried to follow this tutorial: https://itnext.io/anyway-this-is-how-to-use-v-model-with-vuex-computed-setter-in-action-320eb682c976. But even with a computed setter added, I still get the same error. While I am doing exactly this: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#two-way-computed-property.

Comment: if you need to change `selectedDate` then you need a setter. show us the code of the setter too please.

Comment: Probably it is happening because you are updating a property in a nested object. In mutation try to use Vue.set: Vue.set(state.articleSettings, 'date_end', dateValue). Personally I don't like to use setter in computed, I prefer to load the data in mounted/created, change, and commit in state using and action.

Comment: Can it be that if you do not have a set (value) specified, it also gives the reactivity warning? Because now that I implemented that with a commit (instead of an action because of asynchronicity) it suddenly works!